# How can I invite an OP to a chat in order to avoid flooding the comments section?

Tags: support, chat

I've been helping some OP and we've already exchanged some information through the comments section but there's more information we would need to exchange.

I don't want to flood the comments section and I know that there's a way to invite a user to a chat but I couldn't find how it's done, can anyone please assist?